# How To Get Ball Moving Left and Right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have the ball moving diagonal. I need to get it moving left and right at a speed of 2 pixels per update. After it reaches 800 pixels to the right I need to get it to move left.

**Css code**

```
<style>
#animationArea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.pbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

  </style>
```

**JsCode**

```
var dvAnimationArea = document.querySelector("#animationArea");

//create the 'ball' for this animation
var ball = document.createElement('div');
ball.classList.add('pbox');
dvAnimationArea.appendChild(ball);

//position for our 'ball'
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

//start the animation interval
setInterval(update, 30);
function update() {
  ball.style.top = y + "px";
  ball.style.left = x + "px";

  x++;
  y++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left out the JS entirelly.
 This animates the ball 2px at a time.
 I can do this in vanilla js on click if you like, make it pause on hover etc.
 Just let me know what the goal is and how long the animation should take.

```
.pbox {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #FF0000;
border-radius: 25px;
animation:hello 5s infinite steps(400, end);}
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/bVOgaZ

And let me know you want the container to really be 400px wide, that is no typo?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the size of the container should be I expanded it on mine and made it 800px so I could see the ball, but I think I need to use JS because I'm suppose to use one DOM element.

Comment: Tell me, does the ball have to be dynamically created?If no, i'm happy:-)
Is it ok to use css?
Do you need it to be triggered on click?Do you want an animation stop feature on hover or click of some element?jQuery or vanilla JS?
How long should the animation take and where should the ball be displayed initially?

Comment: @jjdouble000
I have updated the code there for you with plain JS.
On hover over the animationArea, the animation starts.
On click of the button, you can stop it, on another click, it will carry on from where it started.

Comment: You are welcome, btw i changed the querySelector simply because when we already have an ID, it's bes to use getElementById.
Not so much because of browser support, this animation will not work in so many IE versions lol, should be fine in the new versions, though:-)

Comment: Thank you! I've got it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94984/discussion-between-jjdouble000-and-damiano-celent).